# What do I do with the error message 'string indices must be integers, not tuple'?

Tags: python, spyder

The middle line of code is the problem and I am not sure why.

```
def extract_month(in_data, month):
     month_data = in_data[np.arange(month-1, len(in_data[:, 0]), 12), :]
     return month_data
```

Comment: As the message says, indices must be integers, not tuple.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a real python beginner, and I'm still not sure how to correct this?

Comment: `len(in_data[:, 0])` ,  this is the statement causing error.

Comment: How can i correct this?

Comment: What does your data look like?  What is the actual error message?  You're not giving people enough to go on to really help you here.

Comment: My data is an array of 456 columns and 4 rows, and I am looking to extract every 12th row from this array

Comment: 456 rows and 4 columns sorry

Comment: The error message says 'string indices must be integers, not tuple'

Comment: That implies that in_data is a string.  Is it?

Comment: No, in_data is a float?